# spring jdbc vs spring data jpa design advice

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

We have to process xmls and convert in to java object which ultimately represent 30 something tables. For each xml we have 500 master records and another 1000 child entities and all this needs to be inserted as one transaction.

I did not see anything about JPA batch inserts, so need some advice which one is better choice Spring jdbc or spring data jpa

Comment: It's really hard to say which is better, that would depend on the amounts of data and how well optimized the written code is. If this is a one off thing, that I would write a simple Java class that would handle it and not even worry about integrating into Spring or any of that. Here is a batch insert link that is useful: http://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/

Comment: Batch operations need to be configured on the underlying JPA provider.  You will need to go through the documentation of the provider you are using to find out how.

Comment: Yes, i did find that EclipseLink provide batch insert along with the jdbc driver support. So I am going with EclipseLink JPA and our oracle driver for batch inserts. Thank you for your help.